# How return array in function() to javascript on wordpress ajax.php with following code:

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

it may seem stupid, but i'm in it for a week, help me ...

the "response" in xhr dev-tools chrome does not leave "0", it never returns the array I need ...

**Javascript code to get data from wordpress**

```
$(document).on("click", "[data-show-home-list-series]", function () {
                var id = $(this).attr("data-show-home-list-series");
                $("[data-show-home-list-series]").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                var $list = $("#homeSliderSerieList");
                $.post("wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", { getHomeSliderSeries: id }, function (html) {
                    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(html);
                    if (data.status == "success") {
                        var listing = data.list;
                        var lister = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                            var row = listing[i];
                            lister.push(seriePoster(row.url, row.rating, row.poster, row.title, row.cat, row.episode));
                        }
                        $list.parent(".itemsList").addClass("fadingOut");
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $list.html(lister.join(""));
                            $list.trigger("destroy.owl.carousel");
                            createItemSlider();
                            $list.parent(".itemsList").removeClass("fadingOut");
                        }, 200);
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
```

**PHP file to return data in array json to javascript show results in html.**

wp-admin/admin-ajax.php (theme/inc/core/ajax.php)

```
function getHomeSliderSeries(){
// i Want see that bellow in xhr response to javascript:    
//{"status":"success","list":{}}

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_getHomeSliderSeries', 'getHomeSliderSeries' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_getHomeSliderSeries', 'getHomeSliderSeries' );
```

My language is not very good, i hope you undestand, thanks atentiton!!

Comment: If you want to use your `getHomeSliderSeries` function through AJAX then you have to tell the PHP script. You can do this by sending an `action` key where the value is the name of the function, for example: `{ action: 'getHomeSliderSeries' }` or `'action=getHomeSliderSeries'`. Without it the server won't know what function the call.

Comment: And you have JavaScript in your PHP function. Instead use an associative array and turn it into JSON with `json_encode()`. Then return the JSON.

Comment: but if i want keep and send data on .php its possible to use post like this?  $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : null

Comment: Check the answer below. If you have any questions, feel free to leave them below the answer and I'll get to them as soon as I can.

Comment: Hi @RuanCabral , please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ajax callback function in functions.php

```
function swt_ajax_data() {
  $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';

  // Create an associative array for the response.
  $responsedata = array(
   'id'       => $id,
  ); 
  $result = array();
  
  // if need featch the data from the template un comment the bellow five lines and commented the sixth line
  //ob_start();
  //include('templatepatj');
  //$opr_html .= ob_get_contents();
  //ob_get_clean();
  // $result['data'] = $opr_html;


  $result['data'] = $responsedata;// POST array data.
  }
  return wp_send_json_success($result);
  }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_swt_ajax_data', 'swt_ajax_data');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_swt_ajax_data', 'swt_ajax_data');
```

Localize your script and pass the admin ajax url

```
// Register the script
  wp_register_script( 'ajax-script', 'path/to/myscript.js' );
   // Localize the script with new data
   $js_array = array(
   'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
);
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'swtobj', $js_array );
// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script' );
```

Try Js as like below.

```
$(document).on("click", "[data-show-home-list-series]", function () {
  var id = $(this).attr("data-show-home-list-series");
  $("[data-show-home-list-series]").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  var $list = $("#homeSliderSerieList");

  var data = {
  'action': 'swt_ajax_data', 'id': id
  };
  $.ajax({
    url: swtobj.ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      var response_data = response.data.data;
      if (response_data != "" || response_data.length != 0) {
        console.log(response_data);
        // write your code here
      } else {
        // write your code here
      }
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: I put that "{action: getHomeSliderSeries, getHomeSliderSeries: id }" and work the response on ajax, thanks a lot !!

Comment: @RuanCabral, can you please mark the answer up voted?

Answer (score 0):

The data you send in `$.post` is missing an `action` property. This property is responsible for telling the `admin-ajax.php` which function that is registered with a `wp_ajax_{function_name}` hook should be called.

The value in the `action` property should match the `function_name` in `wp_ajax_{function_name}` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_{function_name}` to be called properly.

Combine the `action` property with other properties that you want to send to the backend to pass the data that you need to send.

```
// Set the action and get the id.
var action = 'getHomeSliderSeries';
var id = $(this).attr("data-show-home-list-series");

// Create object to send data to backend.
// This must include an action property with 
// the name of the function on the backend.
var postData = {
  action: action,
  id: id,
  example: 'Send any data as a property. You can also nest objects and arrays.'
};

$.post("wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", postData, function(response) {
  if (response.status == "success") {
    console.log(response);
  }
}, 'json'); // Expect JSON from the backend. Now you don't need to parse.
```

Now on the server side your `getHomeSliderSeries` should be called. All the other properties (action included) can now be accessed through the global `$_POST` variable with their corresponding keys.

For a response, create an associative array with the data you want to return. This is the equivalent of an object in JavaScript. Encode the array to JSON and send it back. Now the frontend should see an object as a response.

```
function getHomeSliderSeries(){
  // Get the id from the post request.
  $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : null;
  $example_string = isset($_POST['example_string']) ? $_POST['example_string'] : null;

  // Create an associative array for the response.
  $response = array(
    'status'   => 'success',
    'id'       => $id,
    'example'  => $example_string
  );

  // Return the array as a JSON string.
  return json_encode($response);

  // Cuts connection by stopping the function.
  die(); 
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_getHomeSliderSeries', 'getHomeSliderSeries' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_getHomeSliderSeries', 'getHomeSliderSeries' );
```